# Ralative Layout inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, adapter, android-relativelayout

I've the following Relativelayout, which contains Linearlayout with Labels. This Relativelayout pushed to the custom ListView in custom adapter. I expected to see Relativelayouts one by one, but got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfwEv.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:padding="8sp">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <TextView
        android:text="Водомер 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="4sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
    <TextView
        android:text="Последняя поверка:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
    <TextView
        android:text="Последние показания:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
    <TextView
        android:text="Текущие показания:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linearLayout1"
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageView
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
      android:layout_width="76sp"
      android:layout_height="76sp"
      android:paddingRight="13sp"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
</RelativeLayout>
```

Target layout seems like this. And if I set to this ListView any other custom view, it looks fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:columnCount="1"
    app:rowCount="7">
    <TextView
        android:text="Список водомеров"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.05"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Введите показания водомера"
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.04"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Сделать фото"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.02"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Button
        android:text="Отправить показания"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.15"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <Space
        app:layout_rowWeight="0.3" />
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

How I can fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use the recyclerView, this is the best solution for you problem. Try looking at [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/), you would figure it out.

Comment: I think the problem causes from the TextView which is above the ListView. You should enable "Show layout bound" feature in the Developer options so that you can see a view which causes your problem. Visit here to know how to enable "Show layout bound": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGqJhK0FTjw . Hopes it help

Comment: @LQGioan yep, it's coll tip. So now it looks [like](https://ibb.co/ncsp9Q) my lines have been added to the TextView, not the ListView

Comment: Yes, It is very useful when we develop a layout. You should consider when using `app:layout_rowWeight="xxx"`. Depends on your goal you should use another way to do that.

Comment: You can update your question(include the answer) so that someone else who has the same problem can resolve their problem quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolve my problem I used advice of **LQ Gioan** and replace target GridLayout to LinearLayout with *weightSum* property. In the content elements I'm using *layout_weight* property.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100">
<TextView
        android:text="Список водомеров"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="11"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the TextView above the list as `wrap_content`